# Working with Nullable DateTime in Custom EditorFor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I am trying to create a custom editor for my ASP.NET MVC5 pages, but when the property `TProp` in the example below is a `Nullable<DateTime>` I receive an error. The failure seems to happen on `helper.EditorFor(Property)`. Here is the error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is null, but this dictionary
>   requires a non-null model item of type 'System.DateTime'.

Here is the code:

```
public static IHtmlString CustomEditorFor<TModel, TProp>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProp>> property)
{
    var htmlString =
        "<div class=\"form-group\">" +
            helper.LabelFor(property) +
            "<div class=\"col-md-10\">" +
                helper.EditorFor(property) +
                helper.ValidationMessageFor(property) +
            "</div>" +
        "</div>"
        ;
    return new HtmlString(htmlString);
}
```

**EDIT: Adding Code reference code for for view, viewmodel and editor template**

**View**: Code that is attempting to render the viewmodel's values

```
@model MyApp.Web.ViewModels.ProductViewModel

<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">Upgrade Details</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            @Html.CustomEditorFor(model => model.DateUpgraded)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Viewmodel**: this is the `Nullable<DateTime>` property that is not rendering

```
public Nullable<DateTime> DateUpgraded { get; set; }
```

**EditorTemplate**: editor template for `DateTime`

```
@model DateTime
@Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue,
        new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = ViewData.ModelMetadata.Watermark })
```

Comment: That message is not generated by the extension method, its generated because your view has `@model DateTime` and your passing a `null` to it. (and recommend your use `TagBuilder` to generate your `<div >` elements)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have added more code to show my view and viewmodel. I'm not quite sure I'm following what you mentioned. The viewmodel does contain a nullable datetime property. Can you take a look and expand on your previous comment?

Comment: You still have not given the relevant information. The code you have shown works fine and your extension method itself cannot generate that error. My best guess it that you also have an `EditorTemplate` for `DateTime` which is rendered by your `helper.EditorFor(property)` line of code. Start by changing `helper.EditorFor(property)` to `helper.TextBoxForFor(property)`. If the view renders correctly, show any `EditorTemplates` that your may have for `DateTime`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I tried changing `EditorFor` to `TextBoxFor` and it rendered an empty textbox; no errors. I've added the editor template code for `DateTime`. Would that be affecting things even though my viewmodel's property is a `Nullable<DateTime>`?

Comment: Yes, because its `@model DateTime` (and your passing it `DateTime?`). It needs to be `@model DateTime?`. But your implementation here really makes no sense (you may as well use either an extension method or an `EditorTemplate`, not both). I'll add an answer with a bit more detail in 30 min or so (and showing how to use the `TagBuilder` class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is thrown because you created a custom `EditorTemplate` for `DateTime` which is called by your `helper.EditorFor(property)` in your extension method. This passes a model of `Nullable<DateTime>` to a view which expects a model which is `DateTime` (not nullable).

You can solve the issue by changing the declaration in the template to

```
@model DateTime? // nullable
```

However, using both an extension method which calls an `EditorTemplate` for a simple value type makes little sense and you should be using one or the other.

Using the extension method, your code would be (note this uses the recommended `TagBuilder` class for generating html)

```
public static IHtmlString CustomEditorFor<TModel, TProp>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProp>> property)
{
    var name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(property);
    var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(property, helper.ViewData);
    var formatString = metadata.DisplayFormatString;
    var watermark = metadata.Watermark;

    StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
    html.Append(helper.TextBoxFor(property, formatString, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = watermark }));
    html.Append(helper.ValidationMessageFor(property));
    TagBuilder container = new TagBuilder("div");
    container.AddCssClass("col-md-10");
    container.InnerHtml = html.ToString();
    html = new StringBuilder();
    html.Append(helper.LabelFor(property));
    html.Append(container.ToString());
    container = new TagBuilder("div");
    container.AddCssClass("form-group");
    container.InnerHtml = html.ToString();
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(container.ToString());   
}
```

Comment: Note answer update to correct issue with the watermark (was using the wrong metadata)

Comment: Yes, the updated answer works perfectly! Thanks for the help!